# Filament Balling up on random parts of a print

Tags: print-quality

The skirt prints out ok, but there is balling up of filament on some of the prints.

I am printing 50 small parts at a go, and the last 4 batches were perfect, but the fifth batch had filament problems like on the photo.

Any advice?

Thanks[image: random filament balling]

Answer (score 7):

I experienced that several times if my print temperature was too low. Then, the filament does not stick to the plate very well and prefers to stick to the nozzle which pulls it away. Solution is to increase the temperature by 5 to 10 degrees, at least for the first layers..

Comment: I think I found the solution, someone (not me) left greasy finger marks on the bed.  I only noticed it when the light was at a certain angle and the grease marks were under the problem items. I cleaned the bed it with acetone + microfibre, and it sticks fine as before.  But if it happens again, I will take your advice and raise the temp. BTW, is acetone ok for de-greasing the print bed? thanks!

Comment: Depends on the bed, I prefer Isoprop for that because Acetone is more volatile and agressive.

Comment: It's not available in the shops here, you think hand sanitiser is ok?

Comment: Normally, not. Hand sanitizer often contains incredients which do not evaporate away. In this case acetone is better :D I just buy Isoprop at ebay.